# Whenever User Inputs, hits an Out Of Range Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, outofrangeexception

```
userInput = input();

for x in range(0,len(userInput)):
    if(userInput[x] == " "):
        spaceValue = x;
rawWord = userInput[0:spaceValue];
secWord = userInput[spaceValue+1:];
wordArray = [];
repeats = len(rawWord); #NEW VAR

if (len(rawWord) == len(secWord)):
    for x in range(0,len(rawWord)):
        wordArray.append(secWord[x]);
    for x in range(0,len(rawWord)):
        for z in range(0,len(rawWord)):
            if((rawWord[x] == wordArray[z])): #Line 15 #repeats insted of wordArray[z]
                wordArray.remove(rawWord[x]);
                repeats = repeats - 1;
                break;

    if(len(wordArray) == 0):
        print("YES");
    else:
        print("NO");
else:
    print("NO");
```

### The code supposed to print YES if the 2 words are same length and have the same letters and NO if they don't.

*Error hits at line 15:* `if((rawWord[x] == wordArray[z])):`
**IndexError: list index out of range**

> It works when

1. Words are **same length** and **same letters**.
2. Words are **different length**.
3. Words are **same length** and **all the letters are different**.

> It doesn't work when

1. Words are **same length** and **different letters** but **at least one letter is the same**

Comment: It must be `len(...) - 1`. If it is `len(...)` it will go over.

Comment: By the way, `range(0, len(userInput))` == `range(len(userInput))`

Comment: Which `len(...)` are you speaking of, there are a lot. All of them?

Comment: You are looping over `for z in range(0,len(rawWord)):` and indexing into `wordArray` which you remove things from in the loop.

Comment: @doctorlove so whenever I remove a value, I need to loop 1 less time?

Comment: unrelated to your question, semicolons are unnecessary

Comment: Are you trying to compare words or letters?

Comment: @doctorlove I edited the post, it worked the way you told me, I had to remove 1 loop every time I removed 1 letter because the Array was getting smaller and the loop wasn't (compare letters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, you are looping over `for z in range(0,len(rawWord)):` but indexing into `wordArray` which you remove things from in the loop.

Always be worried if you are removing things you are looping over.

Can I suggest a better/more pythonic solution?

```
from itertools import permutations

userInput = input()
words = userInput.split(' ')
rawWord = words[0]
otherWords = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(words[1])]
if rawWord in otherWords:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

We can make yours work - don't forget to use your repeats count when you index into the `wordArray` on line 15. Or what was line 15.
I have also removed some un-needed punctuation.

```
userInput = input()

for x in range(0,len(userInput)):
    if userInput[x] == " ":
        spaceValue = x
rawWord = userInput[0:spaceValue]
secWord = userInput[spaceValue+1:]
wordArray = [];
repeats = len(rawWord)

if len(rawWord) == len(secWord):
    for x in range(0,len(rawWord)):
        wordArray.append(secWord[x])
    for x in range(0,len(rawWord)):
        for z in range(0,len(rawWord)):
            if (rawWord[x] == wordArray[z-repeats]): #Line 15
                wordArray.remove(rawWord[x])
                repeats = repeats - 1
                break;

    if(len(wordArray) == 0):
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: Thanks the first one works flawless (ofc and the second), but I will keep the first